# Merge two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, merge

I am trying to merge two arrays with the same number of arguments.

Input:

```
first = [[650001.88, 300442.2,   18.73,  0.575,  650002.094, 300441.668, 18.775],
         [650001.96, 300443.4,   18.7,   0.65,   650002.571, 300443.182, 18.745],
         [650002.95, 300442.54,  18.82,  0.473,  650003.056, 300442.085, 18.745]]

second = [[1],
          [2],
          [3]]
```

My expected output:

```
final = [[650001.88, 300442.2,   18.73,  0.575,  650002.094, 300441.668, 18.775, 1],
         [650001.96, 300443.4,   18.7,   0.65,   650002.571, 300443.182, 18.745, 2],
         [650002.95, 300442.54,  18.82,  0.473,  650003.056, 300442.085, 18.745, 3]]
```

To do that I create simple loop:

```
for i in first:
        for j in second:
            final += np.append(j, i)
```

I got i filling that i missing something. First of all my loop i extremely slow. Secondly my data is quite have i got more than 2 mlns rows to loop. So I tried to find faster way for example with this code:

```
final = [np.append(i, second[0]) for i in first]
```

It working far more faster than previous loop but its appending only first value of second array.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use `np.array` and then `np.concatenate`,

```
import numpy as np

first = np.array([[650001.88, 300442.2,   18.73,  0.575,  
                   650002.094, 300441.668, 18.775],
                  [650001.96, 300443.4,   18.7,   0.65,   
                   650002.571, 300443.182, 18.745],
                  [650002.95, 300442.54,  18.82,  0.473,  
                   650003.056, 300442.085, 18.745]])

second = np.array([[1],
                   [2],
                   [3]])

np.concatenate((first, second), axis=1)
```

Where `axis=1` means that we want to concatenate horizontally.

That works for me

Answer (score 15):

Use `np.column_stack`:

```
import numpy as np

first = [[650001.88, 300442.2,   18.73,  0.575,  650002.094, 300441.668, 18.775],
         [650001.96, 300443.4,   18.7,   0.65,   650002.571, 300443.182, 18.745],
         [650002.95, 300442.54,  18.82,  0.473,  650003.056, 300442.085, 18.745]]

second = [[1],
          [2],
          [3]]

np.column_stack([first, second])
```

If you need it as a list, use the method `tolist`:

```
np.column_stack([first, second]).tolist()
```

Answer (score 2):

For this case, `hstack` (because `second` is already 2D) and `c_` (because it concatenates along the second axis) would also work. In fact `c_` would work even if `second` is shape (3,), as long as its length matches the length of `first`.

Assuming `first` and `second` are already numpy array objects:

```
out = np.c_[first, second]
```

or

```
out1 = np.hstack((first, second))
```

Output:

```
assert (out == np.array(final)).all() & (out == out1).all()
```

That being said, all are just different ways of using `np.concatenate`.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply a 5x3 matrix by a 3x2 matrix (real matrix product)

```
import numpy as np
np_1= np.arange(15).reshape(5,3)
np_1
```