# how do I append an array in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have some arrays of different sizes (such as (140,9), (120,9),...,(123,9)). I need to merge all of them into one array. I used the following code, but it said NumPy array does not have `append` attribute. could you please tell me how can I do it?

```
os.chdir("E:/pythoncode/feature") #change directory to downloads folder
files_path = [os.path.abspath(x) for x in os.listdir()]
fnames_transfer = [x for x in files_path if x.endswith(".npy")]
feature=np.zeros((2000,9))
for i in range(len(fnames_transfer)):
    data=np.load(fnames_transfer[i])
    feature.append(feature,data)
```

the error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-98bd45171da9>", line 3, in <module>
    feature.append(feature,data)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: You must be looking for [concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43561622/merge-two-numpy-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps! Comments are added too.

```
os.chdir("E:/pythoncode/feature") #change directory to downloads folder
files_path = [os.path.abspath(x) for x in os.listdir()]
fnames_transfer = [x for x in files_path if x.endswith(".npy")]
feature=np.zeros((2000,9))

feature_new = []#Added empty list to capture all the appended values
for i in range(len(fnames_transfer)):
    data=np.load(fnames_transfer[i])
    #feature.append(feature,data) ##instead of this use extend as the following 
    feature_new.extend([[feature,data]]) #changed the name from "feature" to "feature_new" to not to be confused with the other variable with a same name.
    #if .extend code line didnt work for you open the following line and remove the .extend
    #feature_new.append(feature,data)
```

Comment: when I remove feature from your code, it works. for example feature_new.extend([[data]])

Comment: Quite interesting, is that a good or bad thing? have you tried the .append (the last line)? Otherwise, if all is good, you may accept the code.

Comment: for append, I also just used data, feature_new.append(data)!